How to handle power saving mode with WorkManager?
We have a worker, that runs periodically every 15 minutes. The worker simply fetches an API and updates a Widget accordingly.
We discovered an issue with that, when a user has the power saving feature enabled.
If the worker is enqueued without NetworkType.CONNECTED, the worker runs every 15 Minutes but fails the API request with a java.net.UnknownHostException. This is because of the doze mode, which suspends network traffic.
If the worker is enqueued with NetworkType.CONNECTED, the worker stops working, since the constraint is never met.
The documentation about WorkManager about this issue is very confusing since it states

In addition, WorkManager adheres to power-saving features and best practices like Doze mode, so you don't have to worry about it.

But this does not seem to be the case.
As far as I can see there are three possible solutions for this:

One solution could be to set the worker as expeditet work


Power Management: Power management restrictions, such as Battery Saver and Doze, are less likely to affect expedited work.

It's not guaranteed but just "less likely"

Use the Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS intent, which is strongly discouraged and maybe even violate the Google Play policy.

Using FCM notifications to trigger the worker does not seem convincing at all.


I am quite sure that we are not the first ones with that problem. How did you manage to get around this situation?

Is your concern with work manager not having the network connection when it runs? To me it sounds like WorkManager is doing exactly what it should

You might want to explain in detail what you mean by "when a user uses enables the power saving feature". Bear in mind that this is an area that is often customized by device manufacturers. Beyond that, it feels like the device is behaving how the user wants.

I'd reframe your thinking.  The user is setting power saving modes.  This means he's likely low battery and wants to prevent unnecessary uses of power (it may even be a safety issue if it goes to 0).  Making a network request wakes up the cellular radio, which uses a significant amount of power.  Thus it's to be avoided in power saving mode.  So a periodic task that updates a widget is EXACTLY the type of thing power saving mode should turn off.  If they want the info, they'll run your app.  Respect the user's choices.

@tyczj I expected WorkManager to run the periodic task during the maintenance window of the doze mode in which, the network connection should not be suspended.

@Da_Shizzle Work manager will adjust its execution times when the device is not in use but doze is not the same as putting your phone in battery saving mode which might be the confusion here? And also like has been mentioned, manufacturers mess with battery saving settings so it can be inconsistent across devices
